# I would like the vpn running on my host to be applied to my debian vm running on host

Tags: windows, networking, debian, vpn

I have tried multiple guides online and followed step by step instructions, however I have failed to achieve this.

1. So I started with enabling 2 network adapters for the vm; NAT and host-only.
2. I started up the vm and checked if there were 2 interfaces for the vm (eth0, eth1)
3. Turned both off (`ifdown eth0; ifdown eth1;`)
4. Changed them to DHCP (added `iface eth0 inet dhcp` and `iface eth1 inet dhcp`)
5. Turned on both interfaces (`ifup eth0; ifup eth1`)
6. Found the IP addresses (`ip address show`)
7. Set them as static in `/etc/network/interfaces`

So I repeated these steps again and again up to the point where I can't fix it anymore.

Everytime I do ifup eth0 in step 5, after a while, it times out and says no dhcp offers received.

This is what my interfaces file looks like currently.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    address 192.168.1.77
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254
    dns-search dev.opsv.com

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so I finally achieved what I was trying to get at. Channelling my VM traffic through the VPN.

**NOTE**: I made a rookie mistake and the software that I was using didn't run as administrator automatically even though I was an admin. So for anyone else out there, make sure you right-click and click run as administrator.

I found this by looking at my IP Routing Table on windows by running `netstat -rn` and seeing that routes were not added properly when connecting through the vpn.

I checked the error log of my software which told me that the new routes were not added/updated (because it didn't have admin rights).

I also found that the network adapter configuration for the VM should be the following instead.

**Network Adpater 1 - NAT Network** *(not just NAT)*

You need to add this NAT Network in the preferences of the virtual box not the VM. `File > Preferences > Network > NAT Network Tab > Add one if none, then save`. Enable Network Adapter 1 in VM Settings and assign it to the NAT Network just created.

This is used to interact with other VM's you may have running on your host.
They will also have to have an NAT Network Adapter enabled like this, using the same NAT Network

**Network Adapter 2 - Bridged Adapter**

Enable Network Adapter 2 in VM Settings by clicking on Bridged Adapter.

This is used to route VM traffic to the internet from what I can tell. *Could be better explained. Correct me if I'm wrong.*

**Network Adapter 3 - Host-only Adapter**

You need to add a Host-only Network same as above through `File > Preferences > Network > Host-only Network Tab > Add one if none, then save`. Enable Network Adapter 3 in VM Settings and assign it to the Host-only Network just created by clicking on host-only adapter and selecting the network.

This is used to allow the host to interact with the VM as a node on the network, such as ssh'ing to it from terminal (mac) or PuTTY (windows).

**Update `/etc/network/interfaces`**

Not only that, I have narrowed down what the `/etc/network/interfaces` file should contain, corresponding to the above configuration:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    metric 1

# The secondary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

# The tertiary network interface
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
    metric 2
```

Make sure you restart the VM if you do not know how to use a combination of `ifdown` and `ifup` or `/etc/init.d/networking restart`.

Double check your VM's `ip addr` is right and/or `ip route show` etc.

*Apologies if I haven't explained everything properly, newbie.*